# External css in CI

Tags: css, codeigniter

I have a folder 'css' in the root and all.css inside it.I am using a link for the external css file as

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

base_url being

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/CodeIgniter/';
```

I thought it should work but I am getting the error as

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) .

help please..

Comment: you're missing a / , it should be `<?php echo base_url(); ?>/css/all.css`

Comment: What's your `.htaccess` like? If you're using it to pretty URLs and if I remember correctly you have to add an exclusion for your public folders or it will try to redirect your example request to `http://localhost/CodeIgniter/index.php?css/all.css`.

Comment: attach you project folder structure here.

Comment: Please inspect the complete source(using F12) and check it whether the complete path is correct and file exists there

Comment: Post your .htaccess code if you have or try using this or try this in your .htaccess file
`DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|assets|ckfinder|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
`

Comment: Thanks the htaccess code helped..